# How fast animals habituate to wearing shoes

Tags: behaviour, learning

You probably have seen [hilarious videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZaC6D7GUto) of dogs wearing shoes for the first time. Animals usually very uncomfortable and try to "shake it off", as they seem to consider shoes be some sort of sticky dirt.

I could only find short clips of dogs wearing shoes for the first time, but I would like to know, how fast dogs, or other animals, will learn that shoes are an integral part of their feet and continue with normal stride?

[image]

[From AllDogBoots](https://www.alldogboots.com/Train-Your-Dog-Wear-Boots-a/261.htm), it seems that teaching dog to walk in shoes will take up to 4 days and a lot of treats.

Comment: It probably is the same as making you wear socks full of dry peas and walking, added with dog reasoning whereby they don't know if they will be able to get the socks off. If you put some floppy socks on a yanomami/ a forest tribesperson, so they can walk in the forst with socks, they would take 4 days to get used to it too.